# How to add two map tangs in single xml file in Android

Tags: android

I am creating tab bar in my application. For one tab i set map activity as tab spec content and add overlay on it. now i have to move on next map as user clicks on overlay.
In short I have to create two layouts each on has map and at run time i have to set visibility and one after other.
For that i create one XML layout which has linear layout as root layout and then create two separate relative layouts to hold two maps but it gives me error that unexpectedly closed.

If you know another way to do it please suggest me.
                                                                               Thank You
                                                                               VIkram Kadam

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use more than one map view in a process as it can cause some known conflicts.
Especially not multiple map views in the same activity.

See
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3756&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars